# wp_options flooded with transient API entires

Tags: transient, cache

I make heavy use of the WordPress Transient API. Suddenly a few days ago my `wp_options` table began being flooded with transient entries (2GB worth on average).

Normally WordPress only writes them to the DB if there is not persistent object caching mechanism. However I use [Lite Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lite-cache/)  for object caching and that hasn't changed in months.

Any ideas on why this would start happening?